# React-snap - pageerror at /: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-snap

I have been trying to add react-snap to my vite react app but I constantly get this error message.

```
> react-snap

  pageerror at /: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

✅  crawled 1 out of 1 (/)
ERROR: Invalid namespace
```

And it seems that the terminal get stuck from loading the remaining error message. No error reference gets displayed whatsoever. I read some stackoverflow questions and answers related to react-snap but nothing really dropped one with is esact issue.

I have gone through my package.json and it looks quite alright in my opinion.

**package.json**

```
{
  ...,
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "postbuild": "react-snap",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "compile:sass": "sass --watch src/styles/scss:src/styles/css"
  },
  "reactSnap": {
    "source": "dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.17",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^11.0.0",
    "prerender-node": "^3.8.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet-async": "^2.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.55",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "react-snap": "^1.23.0",
    "sass": "^1.71.0",
    "vite": "^5.1.0"
  }
}
```

Then I checked my route

**Routes.jsx**

```
import {
  Route,
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Applayout from "../components/layout/Applayout";
import { About, Buy, Contact, Home, Service } from "../pages";
import Error from "../components/layout/Error";

export const routes = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route element={<Applayout />} path="/" errorElement={<Error />}>
      <Route index path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
      <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="service" element={<Service />} />
      <Route path="buy" element={<Buy />} />
    </Route>
  ),
  {
    basename: "/",
  }
);
```

**App.jsx**

```
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { routes } from "../routes/Routes";
import { HelmetProvider } from "react-helmet-async";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <HelmetProvider>
        <RouterProvider router={routes} />
      </HelmetProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**main.jsx**

```
import { hydrateRoot, createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import React from "react";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import "../styles/css/root.css";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
if (rootElement?.hasChildNodes()) {
  hydrateRoot(
    rootElement,
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
} else {
  createRoot(rootElement).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
}
```

**vercel.json**

```
{
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/(.*)",
            "destination": "/"
        }
    ]
}
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

I've tried tried commenting out the index route and building the project but it fails and output the same error.

I need help please :(

I'm expecting the project to build successfully and make crawlling the web project easy.

So far I have tried commenting out various routes in the Routes.jsx file to know where the error is from. I do suspect the index directory but it seems to persist after I comment it out.

Comment: Which is the error, the "pageerror at /: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'" or the "ERROR: Invalid namespace"? FWIW I don't believe either of these errors are related to `react-router` in any way. Is it maybe the `rootElement?.hasChildNodes()` check in your `main.jsx` file? Does your environment support the Optional Chaining operator? Where is any "namespace" relevant? I think we need more or better details.

Comment: My environment supports optional chaining. It runs fine when running on development mode but fails on break when the react-snap runs. I thought it was from the main.jsx but I have tweaked it to suit different solutions online but no positive out come so far.
What other info will you need?

Comment: I don't use Vite and have never heard of `react-snap` so I don't suppose I'd be of much help beyond offering some debugging tips. You could try simplifying what you are rendering to try and isolate where the issue originates. Comment out most of the code all the way to where the error doesn't produce, and uncomment one component/element at-a-time until it produces, then repeat the process again in *that* component/element until you get to the specific code causing the problem.

Comment: Alright then... I will do that

Comment: Does the error happen during build or in the browser?

Comment: It seems it was reported on [GitHub but without solution](https://github.com/stereobooster/react-snap/issues/577). I would expect that this happens from Node.js because you use older version that don't support chaining.

Comment: The error happens during build. So do I need to upgrade my node?